# Mongo DB - union of two groups of fields in aggregations

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database of objects with a structure somewhat similar to the following:

```
{
    "processID": value,
    "upstreamAppName": Name,
    "upstreamAppID": ID,
    "downstreamAppName": Name,
    "downstreamAppID": ID
}
```

I want to group all of the apps based on Name and ID, whether upstream or downstream. I want to accomplish this by grouping all unique combinations of `{ "$upstreamAppName", "$upstreamAppID" }`, group all unique combinations of `{ "$downstreamAppName", "$downstreamAppID" }`, then get the union of these two sets. Does anyone tell me what query I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't this `{ "$downstreamAppName", "$upstreamAppID" }` ---> `{ "$downstreamAppName", "$downstreamAppIdD" }` & also `downstreamAppIdD` --> `downstreamAppID`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) & [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/index.html) ,try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            "upstream": [{ $group: { _id: { AppName: '$upstreamAppName', AppID: '$upstreamAppID' } } }, { $group: { _id: '', upstreamArr: { $push: '$$ROOT._id' } } }],
            "downstream": [{ $group: { _id: { AppName: '$downstreamAppName', AppID: '$downstreamAppID' } } }, { $group: { _id: '', downstreamArr: { $push: '$$ROOT._id' } } }]
        }
    }, { $unwind: '$upstream' }, { $unwind: '$downstream' }, { $project: { unionOfStreams: { $setUnion: ['$upstream.upstreamArr', '$downstream.downstreamArr'] } } }])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QsBDWq5L7vd)

**Note :** Additionally you can add `{$project : {_id :0, upstreamAppName:1,upstreamAppID:1 }},` & `{$project : {_id :0, downstreamAppName:1,downstreamAppID:1 }}` before respective `$group` stages for an optimized query.